# Ping magically works on Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, dns, ping, ipv6

There's a remote machine named `JUPITER`, accessible through Win8 DirectAccess. Then just after IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS, I observe the following:

- `ping JUPITER` works and pings to an IPV6 address.
- `nslookup JUPITER` fails.
- `nbtstat -a JUPITER` fails.
- `c:\windowsc:\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` is original (does not contain JUPITER).

How can ping resolve host name if it cannot be found anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Vista started using [LLMNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_Multicast_Name_Resolution) (RFC [4795](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4795)) for local name lookup, as a replacement for the clunky NetBIOS name service.

(For completeness: If you install iTunes, it will come with Bonjour bundled, which is Apple's [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDNS) (RFC [6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762)) implementation, and Windows will become able to resolve names using mDNS. Both LLMNR and mDNS limit themselves to `name.local`, however, all mDNS implementations *require* the domain to be specified, so it does not match your question, while LLMNR does.)

A very good way of finding the answer would be to monitor the network using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Interesting. Is there a tool to resolve LLMNR names, such as NSLOOKUP or NBTSTAT?

Comment: `ping` evidently.

Comment: `ping` doesn't really count as it uses the standard resolver functions, which merge results from *all* supported protocols.

Comment: Found an [nmap script](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/llmnr-resolve.html) that does this.